# Problems with comboBox value and textBox value on C#

Tags: c#

Im beginner on c#, and i really need some clue how to solve this problem.

I created one project in c#, and in one form i have comboBox with value is numbers between 9-20 and a textBox.

all i want is whenever ComboBox is selected, then TextBox will be set to ComboBox value plus 1. 
for example: If ComboBox1 is selected and the value is 11, then TextBox1.Text will be set to 12.

here's my code i've been working on.

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e
{
    textBox1.Text = comboBox1.SelectedIndex.ToString() +1;
}
```

There's nothing's wrong with the code, but i didnt get the value i want, because the result was like if comboBox is selected with value =11, and textBox1.Text is 21, not 12.

thx before :)

Comment: Well, if there's nothing wrong with the code, then I don't see what the problem is. You didn't get the value you want? Well, I didn't get the pony I wanted either... That's life...

Comment: Please elaborate on what "i didnt get the value i want" actually means.

Comment: Instead of assuring us that "There's nothing wrong with the code", why not take a really close look at this fragment, and translate it into English:   comboBox1.SelectedIndex.ToString() + 1; What happens when you add 1 to a string?

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. You should edit your title to make it meaningful.

Comment: You may want to update the title of your question so that it reflects the actual question.

Comment: @Regi Please read [this link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/79508/Mastering-Debugging-in-Visual-Studio-2010-A-Beginn) debugging is a vital skill for any programmer.

Comment: first of all the comboBox value is numbers between 9-20, and with the codes i've been working on, the result wasn't like what i've expected, for example if i selected comboBox1 is 11 and the textBox1.Text is 21, all i want is like making the result in textBox1.Text into 12.

Comment: 'There's nothing's wrong with the code, but i didnt get the value i want' - If I had a £1 for every time I heard that..

Answer (score 7):

you have to first convert `ComboBox.SelectedValue` to int 
then add 1 and 
then convert it to String

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt16(comboBox1.SelectedValue) + 1);
}
```

**Edit :**

If you are developing **Windows Form Application** then try this :

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt16(comboBox1.SelectedItem) + 1);
}
```

Comment: thx for your comment Sac, but apparently that's still not correct answer.

Comment: hmm the comboBox items is number [9-20], with your codes whenever i selected the comboBox the result in textBox is always 1. what im trying to do is, for example if i selected the comboBox with value 13, and the result in textBox should be 14.

Comment: then I think this is alright , this is not the problem.. have you set both `Text Field` and `Value Field` of `ComboBox Item`..??? Write some more code for explaination...  **Getting right error is more important than finding solution in coding**  try debugging and see what do you get in `comboBox1.SelectedValue`???

Comment: hey Sac, it works!! i looked wrong your code before, it should be comboBox.selectedItem not selectedValue! big thx to you :D

Answer (score 2):

`.ToString()` converts the selected index to a `string` type. The addition operator (`+`) converts the integer `1` to a string `"1"`, simply appending the digit 1 to your text. Instead you should preserve the `SelectedIndex` as an integer, perform the addition, then convert to string.

Try the following:

`textBox1.Text = (comboBox1.SelectedIndex + 1).ToString();`

Comment: But `.Text` also is (and expects) a string.

Comment: You're right, sorry I'd assumed the assignment  conversion was implicit as with the addition operator. Fixed.

Comment: i still didnt get the value i want, i've try it and the result was like if comboBox=9, and textBox=1.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to use `SelectedValue` rather than `SelectedIndex` because the former gets the actual value of the Combo Box item while the latter gets the index of the item in the Combo Box.

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e
{
    textBox1.Text = ((int)comboBox1.SelectedValue + 1).ToString();
}
```

Comment: thx for your comment, i've try but the result was error "NullReferenceException was Unhandled".